# IF statement based on condition of mouse keys

Tags: applescript

I want to be able to check the state of Mouse Keys via Applescript, so that the script can spam the 5 key (which will trigger left mouse clicks) ONLY if sticky keys is on. This will allow the script to be turned off using the shortcut to turn off sticky keys (pressing the <kbd>option</kbd> key 5 times).

My code so far:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click menu item 6 of menu 1 --pseudocode
        if value of checkbox "Enable Mouse Keys" is 1 then
            key code 87 --press the "5" key, triggers mouse press
        end if
    end tell

    end tell

    set rn to (random number from 0.8 to 1.0) as text
    return rn
end idle
```

My problem is with the line `click menu item 6 of menu 1` and how to access the "Mouse & Keyboard" section of the Accessibility pane. If it wasn't already obvious, I have very little experience with applescript. >_>

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid having to open the prefpane. By directly reading the value from the Universal Access preference file

```
set plistFile to (path to preferences from user domain) & "com.apple.universalaccess.plist" as string -- Get the  Universal Access plist path of this use
tell application "System Events" to set mouseDriver to value of property list item "mouseDriver" of contents of property list file plistFile -- read only the value for mouse keys
```

This will return *true* or *false* depending if it is on or not.

One caveat with reading the plist directly is any changes done in the User interface may take about 5 seconds more or less to be written to the file.

You can read [here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/propertylists.html) more about [property list items](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/propertylists.html)

Comment: Ooo this is great. I was considering this but i wasn't sure of how responsive the file would be to the changes in the pref pane.

Answer (score 0):

Update to @markhunte post above for OS 10.14 Mojave (might work on earlier versions too):

```
set plistFile to (path to preferences from user domain) & "com.apple.universalaccess.plist" as string -- Get the  Universal Access plist path of this use
tell application "System Events" to set mouseDriver to value of property list item "stickyKey" of contents of property list file plistFile -- read only the value for mouse keys
```

plist item name "mouseDriver" changed to "SickyKey"